# SQL does not show me the time (hour by day)

Tags: oracle11g

SQL does not show me the time, I have a business day table, and I need that for each business day it shows me a time range from 9 to 19 hours to then show the number of transactions per hour, for each day of the month.

I can not generate stored procedure only query can be performed not to alter the database by company policy

I have a query like that.

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(cd.days, 'yyyymmdd') AS fechaTransaccion,
    NVL(SUM(data.numTransacionExitosa),0)       AS numTransacionExitosa,
    NVL(SUM(data.numTransactionPendiente),0)    AS numTransactionPendiente
FROM
    calendardays cd
LEFT JOIN
    data
ON
    cd.days = data.settledate
WHERE
    cd.DAYs BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(to_date(20200201, 'yyyymmdd'), 'MM'),-1) AND ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(TRUNC(to_date(20200201, 'yyyymmdd'))),-1)
and substr(SETTLEDATE, 10, 2) between 9 and 19
GROUP BY
    cd.days,  substr(SETTLEDATE, 10, 2) 
ORDER BY
    cd.days
```

i need show like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmdUN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand/answer without seeing your data, but if you need to extract hour from date, follow the below example:

`select extract(hour from cast(sysdate as timestamp)) hour from dual;`